# Как писать в разговорных выражениях: Бог или бог?

Tags: орфография, фразеология, прописная-строчная

На сегодняшнее время. В таких общеизвестных выражениях, как *слава богу, ей-богу, бог/боже мой, не дай бог, бог с тобой, с богом, ради бога, видит бог (видит бог, я не знал)*.

*Не дай бог тебя опять уволили.

Иди с богом.

О мой бог, что с тобой случилось.

Да ради бога.

Не знаю, ей-богу.*

Раньше всегда писал *не дай боже* и нормально было, а сейчас рекомендуют писать *не дай Боже*. Как все-таки правильно?

Comment: С маленькой, а также "я не верю в бога" и "бога нет". Бог с большой пишут только христиане и иудеи. Хотя тоже зависит от того, что имеется ввиду, но лучше с маленькой).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Грамота.ру**](http://gramotanew.isi.ru/spravka/letters/56-ortho)

> ...рекомендуется написание со строчной буквы:
> <...>
> 2. В устойчивых сочетаниях, употребляющихся в разговорной речи вне связи с религией: *не бог весть, бог знает что, бог с ним, не дай бог, ради бога, как бог на душу положит, боже упаси, ей-богу* и т. д.  Невозможна прописная буква в таком, например, контексте: *у него всё не слава богу*.

*Не дай **б**ог комиссару бригады оформить орден поменьше, чем командиру.* В. Быков, Болото. *Не дай **б**оже заглушить, задушить в нас это физиологическое явление, которое служит нам отдыхом и отрадою за слезы, проливаемые нами тоже по законам натуры нашей и жизни.* П. Вяземский, Старая записная книжка.
[**НЕ ДАЙ / ПРИВЕДИ БОГ / БОЖЕ / ГОСПОДЬ**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_467)

Comment: А как правильно: "я не верю в бога" и "бога нет"? С прописной или строчной?  (Это из комментариев.)

Comment: @Sharon  "Полный академический справочник «Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации» (М., 2006 и более поздние издания) рекомендует писать с прописной буквы слово *Бог* как название единого верховного существа в монотеистических религиях. Нормативное написание: *верить в Бога, молиться Богу*".  // С уважением к верующим (и как имя собственное) я бы написал с большой: "Я не верю в Бога".

Comment: Спасибо. Правда, мне кажется, что все зависит от ситуации, от темы разговора. Буратино вот написал со строчной буквы. Может, речь бывает не только о монотеистических религиях.